# How to Embed google maps in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm been trying to embeded a google map within a react component with no success. I'm not sure why and tutorials online seem to have outdated versions of react and google maps.

My component below. The HTML document was taken from [google maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map).

```
import React from 'react'
import scriptLoader from 'react-async-script-loader'

class Gmaps extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map, {
      zoom: 4, 
      center: uluru
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>   
        <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
        <div id="map" ref="map"></div>
        <script>
          {function initMap() {
            var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 4,
              center: uluru
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: uluru,
              map: map
            });
          }}
        </script>
      </div>
      )
    }
  }

export default scriptLoader(
['https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY']
) (Gmaps)
```

Apparently I need to use react `ref` to load the map, but not too sure how.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can use simple wrapper around Google Maps Javascript API - like react-google-maps

Answer (score 1):

Source from [here](http://www.klaasnotfound.com/2016/11/06/making-google-maps-work-with-react/)

```
class Gmaps extends React.Component {

    ...

    componentDidMount() {
        // Connect the initMap() function within this class to the global window context,
        // so Google Maps can invoke it
        window.initMap = this.initMap;
        // Asynchronously load the Google Maps script, passing in the callback reference
        loadJS('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap')
    }

    initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map.getDOMNode(), { ... });
    }

    render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    ...
                    <div ref="map" style="height: '500px', width: '500px'"><⁄div>
                <⁄div>
            );
    }
})

function loadJS(src) {
    var ref = window.document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    var script = window.document.createElement("script");
    script.src = src;
    script.async = true;
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(script, ref);
}
```

Comment: use window in not the best idea (there can be issues with SSR)

Comment: thanks Firice. I saw that tutorial. However it didnt work for me. also it looks very hacky. Would there be a better solution? Yes, also SSR could be an issue.